# selecting a variable amount of records based on the sum of columns values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance

I have a table with a column that's a float. 
I order the table by created_at:
Foo.order(:created_at)

I want to select from that ordered table a variable amount of records.

Its varied because I need to sum the values of the float column on the records to get a value greater than a target float.

So lets say I have ordered my table above and it has these 4 records, with their float values:

1. 30
2. 50
3. 40
4. 20

if my target float is 60, i want to return just the first 2 records
if my target float is 100, i want to return the 3 records
if my target float is 20, i want just the first record

Is there a way to do this in active record or straight sql?

Is it faster to do it this way, or should I query for all the records and use only the ones i need?

Edit:

Building on the problem, I want to select from tables that have been first ordered by one of their columns lets say fizz:

```
select foo1.id, 
    (select coalesce(sum(f2.amount),0) 
     from (select * from foo order by fizz) f2 
     where f2.id < f1.id) as amount_total 
from (select * from foo order by fizz)
group by f1.id
having amount_total < target_total
```

This works, but isnt ideal, as you're ordering the table twice. Is there a way to order the table once, and then use it for both f1 and f2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table `foo` with `id`, `bar` and `fizz` columns:

```
id bar fizz
-- --- ----
1  30  3
2  50  2
3  40  1
4  20  4
```

You can do this in SQL but I don't think you could do it in ActiveRecord.

```
select f1.id, f1.bar, f1.fizz, 
       (select coalesce(sum(f2.bar),0) 
          from foo f2 
         where f2.fizz < f1.fizz) as bar_total 
  from foo f1 
 group by f1.id, f1.bar, f1.fizz
having bar_total < TEST_VALUE
 order by f1.fizz;
```

**Note**: As pointed out in the comments below you may or may not need the `group by` clause.  `sqlite3` requires it but `mysql` does not.

For example, if TEST_VALUE = 60:

```
id bar fizz bar_total
-- --- ---- -------------
3  40  1    0
2  50  2    40
```

If TEST_VALUE = 100:

```
id bar fizz bar_total
-- --- ---- -------------
3  40  1    0
2  50  2    40
1  30  3    90
```

If TEST_VALUE = 20:

```
id bar fizz bar_total
-- --- ---- -------------
3  40  1    0
```

Comment: I connected to my sqlite3 database using 

"sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3"

the query that ended up working was 


"select foo1.id, (select coalesce(sum(f2.amount),0) from foo f2 where f2.id < f1.id) as amount_total
from foo f1
group by f1.id
having amount_total < total"

sqlite3 told me: "Error: a GROUP BY clause is required before HAVING"

Comment: @user2761764 - thanks :)  I wasn't sure what database you were using - what I did originally worked on mysql but I just tried it on sqlite and got the same error you did.  I've amended my answer now to include the `group by` clause.

Comment: Building on the problem, I want to select from tables that have been first ordered by one of their columns lets say fizz:

select foo1.id, (select coalesce(sum(f2.amount),0) from (select * from foo order by fizz) f2 where f2.id < f1.id) as amount_total from (select * from foo order by fizz) group by f1.id having amount_total < target_total

This works, but isnt ideal, as you're ordering the table twice. Is there a way to order the table once, and then use it for both f1 and f2?

Comment: Does that do what you need?  It only orders once by fizz and changes the building of the running total to that ordering by comparing the value of fizz rather than id.

Comment: I tried it out and it looks right, thanks man, you hit it right on the head.

Comment: No worries.  Technically you should raise a new question when you need to ask something else rather than edit the original, but it was a small change so it's cool ;)

Answer (score 0):

maybe do something like this:

```
def check_sum(target)
   if target == 60.00
     return Foo.order(:created_at).limit(2)
   elsif target == 100.00
     return Foo.order(:created_at).limit(3)
   elsif target == 20.00
     return Foo.order(:created_at).limit(1)
   end
end
```

you can also sort it ASC/DESC example `Foo.order("created_at DESC")`

Comment: thats not really what im looking for, id like the limit logic to be in the sql, rather than ruby. plus what you did doesnt work for different values